# Flutter, how to use switch case for bottomnavigationbar?

Tags: flutter

Im a beginner in flutter, and I will like to use switch case to route to another pages, I did try to do it but it doesn't work, can anyone tell me what did I done wrong???

Hope someone can solve my problem
Hope someone can solve my problem
Hope someone can solve my problem
Hope someone can solve my problem
Hope someone can solve my problem
Hope someone can solve my problem

```
class BottomNavigationEzyMember extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavigationEzyMember({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState createState() =>
      _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState();
}

class _BottomNavigationEzyMemberState extends State<BottomNavigationEzyMember> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  var bottomTextStyle =
      GoogleFonts.inter(fontSize: 12, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500);

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        (index) {
      switch (_selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
          break;
        case 1:
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/cardpage');
          break;
      }
    };
    return Container(
      height: 64,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: mFillColor,
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
              spreadRadius: 2,
              blurRadius: 15,
              offset: const Offset(0, 5))
        ],
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
          topRight: Radius.circular(24),
        ),
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 0
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/home.svg'),
            title: Text('Home', style: bottomTextStyle),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 1
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/order.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'My Card',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 2
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/watch.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Watch List',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: _selectedIndex == 3
                ? SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account_colored.svg')
                : SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/account.svg'),
            title: Text(
              'Account',
              style: bottomTextStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: mBlueColor,
        unselectedItemColor: mSubtitleColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedFontSize: 12,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. please take a moment and read this article [ask] about how to asking questions also read this article [mre] about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement. Good luck 

Answer (score 2):

Remove switch statement from under `buildContext`; you will use switch statement under `_onItemTapped`.

```
  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      print("working");      
      _selectedIndex = index;
      switch (_selectedIndex) {
        case 0:
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/homepage');
          break;
        case 1:
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/cardpage');
          break;
      }

    });
  }
```